# KeyError in Empty Dictionary Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I am doing a simple task: find intersection of two arrays in Python.

I wrote the code:

```
def intersect(nums1, nums2):
    """
    :type nums1: List[int]
    :type nums2: List[int]
    :rtype: List[int]
    """

    hash_2 = {}

    for x in nums2:
        if x in hash_2:
            hash_2[x] = 1
        else:
            hash_2[x] =  hash_2[x] + 1

    intersection = []

    for x in nums1:
        if x in hash_2:
            if hash_2[x] >0:
                intersection.append(x)
                hash_2[x] =  hash_2[x] - 1

    return intersection    

print(intersect([],[1]))
```

I get :

```
    line 14, in intersect
    hash_2[x] =  hash_2[x] + 1
KeyError: 1
```

I tried debugging but it is not helping. Why is the python program sending 1 to else condition when the dictionary itself is empty?

Is this some issue in Python's dictionary that you should not search in empty dictionaries?

Comment: That looks like a work for `collections.Counter()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in `x`, `1`, isn't in `hash_2` (since `hash_2` is empty), so the `else` branch is taken.  And since `x` isn't in `hash_2`, you get a `KeyError` trying to access `hash_2[x]`.

It looks like you want your test to be `if x not in hash_2`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the point of `hash_2` and what it is, But if you want to calculate the intersection of two sequences here is a solution:

```
def intersection(seq1, seq2):
    result = list()
    for item in seq1:
        if item in seq2:
            result.append(item)
    return result

def main():
    a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 'salam', 'bye', ['!', '*']]
    b = [10, 11, 23, 30, 'salam', 'not', ['!', '*']]
    print(intersection(a, b))

main()
```

Comment: yours is a O(n squared) solution, using hash table makes it O(n) at the expense of O(n) space